# Need to flatten column to a single row per group with a sum of the column values for each group

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have been trying to flatten the data in my query into a single row for each group.  I thought using a CASE statement would achieve this, but it still places the results in separate rows.  I am also using a CASE statement in the Group By clause.

```
    Actual Results:                     Desired Result:
    aonBom                      Fees    aonBom                      Fees
    AA201   D02440120105        9.00    AA201   D02440120105        15.00
    AA201   D02440120105        6.00    AA201   D14251210105        9.00
    AA201   D14251210105        9.00    AA201   D16007120115        9.00
    AA201   D16007120115        9.00    AA702   D02440120110        15.00
    AA702   D02440120110        9.00
    AA702   D02440120110        6.00
```

My current sql statement is:

```
SELECT
    CASE a.productid
        WHEN 6 THEN a.productid + space(2) + a.cusotmerid + p.progcode+ w.level 
        WHEN 7 THEN a.productid + space(1) + a.cusotmerid + p.progcode+ w.level
        ELSE a.productid + space(3) + a.cusotmerid + p.progcode + w.level
    END AS aonBom,  
    CASE        
        WHEN (s.sku IN('80-53-0000', '80-52-TTSB')
            or s.sku BETWEEN '90-00-0000' AND '90-00-9999')
        THEN sum(s.retail)
    END as Fees
FROM
    l
        INNER JOIN item ON l.product = i.prime
        INNER JOIN item AS s ON l.compon =s.prime
        INNER JOIN a ON i.prime = a.product
        INNER JOIN p ON a.program = p.prime
        INNER JOIN w ON a.award = w.prime
        INNER JOIN c ON p.customerid = c.prime
WHERE
    c.active = 'Active'
    AND p.status = 'Active'
GROUP BY    
    CASE a.productid
        WHEN 6 THEN a.productid + space(2) + a.cusotmerid + p.progcode+ w.level 
        WHEN 7 THEN a.productid + space(1) + a.cusotmerid + p.progcode+ w.level
        ELSE a.productid + space(3) + a.cusotmerid + p.progcode + w.level
    END,
    s.sku,
    c.active, 
    p.status
HAVING
    s.sku IN ('80-53-0000', '80-52-TTSB') OR
    (s.sku BETWEEN '90-00-0000' AND '90-00-9999')
ORDER BY
    aonBom
```

I have readyu several articles on the web that using CASE statements is the way to flatten data, just not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, I would move the `SUM` from the inside, to the outside, remove the last 3 items from the `GROUP BY` and remove the `HAVING` statement

Something like

```
SELECT
    CASE a.productid
        WHEN 6 THEN a.productid + space(2) + a.cusotmerid + p.progcode+ w.level 
        WHEN 7 THEN a.productid + space(1) + a.cusotmerid + p.progcode+ w.level
        ELSE a.productid + space(3) + a.cusotmerid + p.progcode + w.level
    END AS aonBom,  
    sum(CASE        
        WHEN (s.sku IN('80-53-0000', '80-52-TTSB') or s.sku BETWEEN '90-00-0000' AND '90-00-9999')
            THEN s.retail
        END) as Fees 
    FROM l
        INNER JOIN item ON l.product = i.prime
        INNER JOIN item AS s ON l.compon =s.prime
        INNER JOIN a ON i.prime = a.product
        INNER JOIN p ON a.program = p.prime
        INNER JOIN w ON a.award = w.prime
        INNER JOIN c ON p.customerid = c.prime WHERE
    c.active = 'Active'
    AND p.status = 'Active' GROUP BY    
    CASE a.productid
        WHEN 6 THEN a.productid + space(2) + a.cusotmerid + p.progcode+ w.level 
        WHEN 7 THEN a.productid + space(1) + a.cusotmerid + p.progcode+ w.level
        ELSE a.productid + space(3) + a.cusotmerid + p.progcode + w.level
    END 
    ORDER BY
    aonBom
```